# Running time of Goldberg's densest subgraph algorithm for integer edge weighted graphs

Tags: weighted-graphs

The running time of the original non-weighted algorithm is  $\mathcal{O}(M(n, n + m)\,log(n))$,
where $M(n, m)$ is the execution time for finding a min-cut in a network with $n$ nodes and $m$ edges and $log(n)$ is the number of times the while loop must be executed.

The changes he makes to the original solution are:

- the capacities of the edges are set equal to the weights of the corresponding edges,
- the degree of each node is now equal to the sum of the weights of the edges incident on the node,
- and the upper bound for highest density *u* starts from *W* (the sum of all weights of the graph)

Meanwhile the smallest distance between two values of the solution remains $$\frac{1}{n(n-1)}.$$

My question is, the only thing that changes, from an asymptotic perspective on the running times, is the number of times the while loop is executed, right?
I mean, if before it was upper bounded by $log(n)$ now it's upper bounded by $log(W)$, everything else look the same to me.

So it is fair to say that the running time for the integer edge weighted case is
$\mathcal{O}(M(n, n + m)\,log(W))$ ?